# Just installed Ubuntu 13.10, can't get Netflix desktop to work

Tags: 13.10, netflix, moonlight, pipelight, netflix-desktop

I upgraded from Ubuntu 12.04 today and had always used the Netflix desktop and never had a problem with it. But after doing a clean install of Ubuntu 13.10, it seems like it's thinking after I click on the Netflix application (round clock-looking pointer for a couple of seconds) and then nothing happens.
I tried uninstalling the desktop app and reinstalling, but that didn't work. I'm reading that Pipelight is the best way to go?  But following the instructions on [this website](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/08/pipelight-use-silverlight-in-your-linux.html) 
did not work either.  But I am unsure about how to follow the last 2 instructions Update 1 and Update 2. Note: I'm not getting any error messages at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I Spent  two days to finally got it working first of all you need to have wine installed if you do not  open  a terminal ctrl +alt +t 
and type:

```
sudo apt-get install wine then (Press enter)

rm -Rf ~/.wine-browser
```

Uninstall and purge netflix-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get purge netflix-desktop
```

I'm assuming you've added the PPA repository, if not:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo apt-get update
```

Install netflix-desktop:

```
sudo apt-get install netflix-desktop
```

When you run netflix-desktop application. it will ask to install moonlight and wine gecko say 'yes' to both

Comment: I did all that and at the end of loading wine gecko, netflix didn't open.  So that's when I tried to open it and nothing came up.

Comment: have you tried to go to the smart scope type netflix and click on the netflix icon?

Comment: Yes. It looks like it's about to do something and then just quits.  No error messages.

Comment: yes i know what you mean same thing happened to me I ended up un installing netflix and then did what i posted before  after that somehow it worked just fine

Comment: Seems to have worked.

Comment: glad to hear that :D

Comment: I was just wondering if you use hola unblocker in Firefox it is been reported as the cause for some laptops to heat when running ubuntu

Comment: No I don't use hola unblocker.  Though, since I posted this question I've installed Cairo Dock and my laptop never runs hot anymore. @sebas

Answer (score 2):

I was using firefox and couldn't get that to work.  Tried chromium and same thing.  So I downloaded Chrome and got the User Agent Switcher and switched to Windows Firefox 15 from the extension preferences and finally, Louie is playing on Netflix.

Comment: So, after watching netflix through Chrome for about half an hour, my laptop froze, I had to unplug it to turn it off. Then I noticed that it was burning up.  pluginloader.exe seems to be the culprit. So, I've quit using Chrome and still don't have a solution.  Thinking about doing another clean install. Sorry, but this answer is not a good one, at least with the hardware I'm using.  Also, I had already installed tlp.  And with Netflix not running, my computer is back to a nice cool temperature.

Answer (score 1):

No need for netflix desktop

Netflix works fine with chrome in ubuntu
Hbo nordic and magine tv works fine with firefox if pipelight with widewine and silverlight enabled.

Comment: Now with HBO Nordic update it stopped working. Netflix works fine with Chrome or Firefox + Pipelight + User Agent.